# $refs doesn't work in dev but local vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to show popup in particular case. I added my product popup default.vue

```
<div class="mainContainer">
        <Nuxt/>
        <ErrorPopup/>
        <ProductPopUp
          ref="confirm"
        />
</div>
```

and I can access that ref in another component Account.vue and trigger a button like this

```
await this.$root.$children[2].$refs.confirm.open();
```

this works in my local environment but it doesn't work in dev environment
What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Even if this one works in dev, it's probably not the way to go here (using `children`, indexes etc...). A [repro] will indeed greatly help here.

Comment: Nope kissu. @kissu